# How does web image caching work and why does this website I created only work properly offline

Tags: javascript, jquery, caching, load, settimeout

This is my first post, so please don't get mad if I did something wrong.  This is the most complex website I've ever made.  When I host it on my own apache server using ngrok, it does the same thing...

So this is the website hosted:

https://zanemechem.000webhostapp.com/

offline:

https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BxbmcM0U2BHcRVBVZzlwMml2QmM/view?usp=sharing

Basically, It is designed so that when you load the website, the images all get put in the cache of your browser, and then when you scroll down, that movement gets translated into changing the gifs which are the background out, and then placing a placeholder png over them.

offline, the website works perfectly, but hosted, the animations load properly, but after playing around with it, they break, and stop loading.

I've played around a bit with a setTimeout function, to make sure the png doesn't load too fast, but it doesn't seem to work.

The files are also very small for gifs, so the size of the file can't be the root of the problem.  I believe it has to do with this section of the js:

```
function createImage(image,gif,previous){
  $("firstgif").css({backgroundImage:"none"});
  var img = document.createElement('img');
  img.src = image;
  $("#loader").show();
  $("#loader").css({backgroundImage: "url("+previous+")"});
  console.log(previous);
  $(img).on("load", function(){

  setTimeout(function(){$("#loader").hide();
  $(gif).css({backgroundImage: "url("+img.src+'#' + Math.random()+")"})},250);
});
```

I feel like there is something major I am missing but don't have the knowledge to find it.  If anyone here possesses that knowledge, help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need to control the gif playback (gifs only have the option of playing once, looping for a set number of plays, or looping infinitely), you will need an external lib. It will parse the frames and provide you with methods for controlling playback.

There are many options for this, but here is one I've used. It works. https://github.com/buzzfeed/libgif-js

Comment: That looks really good.  I'm going to try to implement it, but the library you posted looks like it will have native support for the stuff I wanted to do instead what I had done before, which was really just a bunch of stuff hacked together. Thank You!!